# Java read xml file recursive without for loop

Tags: java, recursion

I'm currently trying to create a completely recursive method (without iteration like for loop) that reads an Xml file and returns the names and values of the nodes.

I've come this far:

```
 private static void getNodes(Node node){
         System.out.println("Node: " + node.getNodeName());
         NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
         for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
             Node currentode = nodeList.item(i);
             if (currentode.getNodeValue() != null && currentode.getNodeValue().contains("\n") == false){
                 System.out.println(" Value: " +  currentode.getNodeValue());
             }
             if (currentode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 Element element = (Element) currentode;
                 getNodes(element);
             }
         }
     }
```

The call:

```
File xmlFile = new File("src/users.xml");

Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

getNodes( doc.getDocumentElement());
```

The Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user id="1">
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
        <lastname>Brown</lastname>
        <occupation>programmer</occupation>
    </user>
    <user id="3">
        <firstname>Lucy</firstname>
        <lastname>Gordon</lastname>
        <occupation>teacher</occupation>
    </user>
</users>
```

The output:

```
Node: users
Node: user
Node: firstname
 Value: Peter
Node: lastname
 Value: Brown
Node: occupation
 Value: programmer
Node: user
…
```

How can I get the same result without using a for loop or additional method (complete recurisve with one method)?

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't use recursion with XML (or most tree structured data) and instead practice using the Visitor pattern. It's very handy to be able to walk a DOM and convert it to the data model you require in your program. Not what you're looking for, but I thought I'd put that on the table :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The goal of this implementation is just to learn recursion well

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 You’ll need to explain your position more clearly—recursive tree algorithms are common (and can be used with visitors).

Comment: Or you can answer her question for him/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void getNodes(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        System.out.println("Node: " + node.getNodeName());
        getNodes(node.getChildNodes(), 0);
    }
}

private static void getNodes(NodeList nodes, int i) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);

    if (node == null)
        return;

    if (node.getNodeValue() != null && !node.getNodeValue().contains("\n"))
        System.out.println(" Value: " + node.getNodeValue());

    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        getNodes(node);

    getNodes(nodes, i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for a school project or for learning.

Typically we deal with a collection of things recursively by treating the collection as if it were a linked list, with a *head* (the first item in the collection) and a *tail* (the rest of the collection).

A basic example using arrays of strings:

```java
private static void printStrings(String[] strings) {
    if (strings.length > 0) {
        String head = strings[0];
        System.out.println(head);    
        String[] tail =  Arrays.copyOfRange(strings, 1, strings.length);
        printStrings(tail);
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = {"One","Two","Three"};
    printStrings(strings);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This is a bit of a simple example so I wanted to do something difficult

Comment: You should be able to take this and switch it to work in terms of `Node`, you doing the difficult bit is how you learn.